# More efficient STL like way of performing an operation,

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a more STL like/efficient way of doing the following

```
for (int i=0 ; i< N ; ++i)
{
    mystruct[i].key   = myfunction(xp[i], yp[i], zp[i]);
    mystruct[i].index = i;
}
```

where mystruct is of type

```
struct KeyIndex
{
    int key;
    int index;

};
```

xp, yp , zp are three floating point arrays of size `N`

```
double xp[N];
double yp[N];
double zp[N];
```

and myfunction is some function having signature `int myfunction (int, int ,int)`

If it is required for me to change the function `myfunction` into a functor for STL purposes that is ok.

Comment: I think this is one of the cases where looking for a functional-style solution is a useless complication, making your code more obscure for no real reason.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: One assumes this is just a simple exercise to get them used to using functors.

Comment: Based on the member names, it sounds like you're trying to build a map-like structure. You might want to consider something like: `std::map<int, int> mymap; for (int i=0; i<n; i++) mymap[myfunction(xp[i], yp[i], zp[i])] = i;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
struct TheFunctor
{
    double *xp, *yp, *zp;
    int idx;

    TheFunctor(double * Xp, double * Yp, double * Zp) : xp(Xp), yp(Yp), zp(Zp), idx(0) {};

    KeyIndex operator()()
    {
         KeyIndex ret;
         ret.key=idx++;
         ret.value=myfunction(*(xp++), *(yp++), *(zp++));
    }
};

TheFunctor fn(xp, yp, zp);
std::generate(begin(mystruct), end(mystruct), fn);
```

But it surely isn't faster, and it's way more obscure for no good reason. As stated in the comment, this is one of the cases where a simple `for` loop is way better.

Comment: I agree the for loop is better but there are other ways to improve the original (Add a constructor for KeyIndex that takes an int). But in my opinion not significantly better and they will not be more efficient (as you mentioned)) and it does not look more STL like.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any structure in the data or in the `myfunction` function that may allow you to calculate the `N` key values without actually evaluating `mufunction` `N` times?

Say, you have a function `sum(n)` which calculates the sum of the elements of an array `arr` up to index `n`. If you call it with `n` = 1234 then you don't need to call it for `n` = 1235 because that would add the first 1234 numbers for no reason. In this case `sum`(1235) = `sum`(1234) + `arr`[1234], much faster to calculate.

Another optimization would be if your (xp, yp, zp) parameters appear multiple times in the arrays. In that case you would unnecessarily call `myfunction` a large number of times with the same parameters, hopefully generating the same results.

If this is so and the data arrays are large but contain a far smaller set of distinct values you can memoize the results in a cache of sorts. Before calling myfunction you check the cache to see if you haven't already calculated the results. Use the cached value if you did or calculate and add it to the cache if you didn't.

Otherwise you are not going to optimize that in any meaningful way and you should instead aim to make it as readable as possible.